# When I try to use .push inside a loop it seems to start one stage ahead of interval number, which seems to cause an overflow?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this function:

```
function generation(input_text, characters, target_text, mutation_rate, amount_offspring) {
var generationObject = [{string:"", score: 0}];
var evolved_string = "";
var best_offspring = {string:"", score: 0};

for(var i = 0; i <= amount_offspring; i++) {
    evolved_string = evolve(input_text, characters, mutation_rate)
    console.log("E= " + evolved_string);
    generationObject.push({
            string: evolved_string,
            score: score(target_text, evolved_string)
    });
    console.log(generationObject[i]);

    // if there are more then 2 elements in the object array. 
       Check if the current offspring has a higher score then the previous one.
       If it does, its the best offspring
    if (generationObject.length > 1) {
        if (generationObject[i].score > best_offspring.score) {
            best_offspring.string = generationObject[i].string;
            best_offspring.score = generationObject[i].score;
        }
    }
    // if there only is one offspring. Its the best, by defult.
    else {
        best_offspring.string = generationObject[i].string;
        best_offspring.score = generationObject[i].score;
    }

    // increment generations
    generations++;  
    return best_offspring.string;
}
```

This loop is part of a larger program, http://pastebin.com/tRU1KYP7 and http://pastebin.com/MDt3M2s5, where it takes a string as an input, copies the string `amount_offspring` times while mutates one of the characters. My error is when it tries to push the `evolved_string` and the `score` to the `generationObject` array by doing `.push()`.

It seems like by doing this it skips the `generationObject[0]`. Why is that? Can I use any other method to add to my array instead? thx!

EDIT:
Here I did an console output so you can see more clearly what i mean!

```
functions.js:4 Input= xkt
functions.js:13 Evolved= xkr
functions.js:18 Object {string: "", score: 0}
functions.js:13 Evolved= xks
functions.js:18 Object {string: "xkr", score: 0}
functions.js:13 Evolved= xct
functions.js:18 Object {string: "xks", score: 0}
```

But here you can see that `functions.js:18 Object {string: "", score: 0}` is like this on the first run. Why?

Comment: You're initializing the array such that it starts off with one object in it.

Comment: @Pointy Ok! How would I go about and  initialize it so that it is empty? `var generationObject = [{string:, score:}];` like this?

Comment: No, like this: `var generationObject = [];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize the array with a single object:

```
var generationObject = [{string:"", score: 0}]; //use var generationObject = []; instead
```

Your overflow error comes from here:

```
i <= amount_offspring; //should be i < amount_offspring, since you start at 0
```

Comment: YES! this did the trick, thank you!! Didnt knew that you could initialize and object array like that.